# Could not create DB Connection due to SQL-Cipher issue when migrating from Xamarin to .net Maui

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, migration, maui, sqlcipher

I can create a DB Connection in Xamarin using the following code:

```
    var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(dbPath, true, dbPassword, postKeyAction: c =>
    {
        c.Execute("PRAGMA cipher_compatability = 3");
    });

 SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(options);
```

But the same code when I try to use it in .Net Maui with the .net7.0 version. It is not working and giving the following Error.

> **SQLite.SQLiteException: file is not a database Result:**
>
> **SQLite.SQLite3+Result.NonDBFile**

**Nu-get Package which I have used:**

> Xamarin  => sqlite-net-sqlcipher version:1.8.116
>
> .NetMaui => sqlite-net-pcl version:1.8.116

Comment: Well aren't you using the Wrong NuGet in that case evidently

Comment: @FreakyAli Am using the Nuget package which they mentioned in the dotnet documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: But you need Cipher compatibility that comes with sqlcipher, change your Nuget and things will work fine

Comment: @FreakyAli Can you tell me which Package i should use here to solve this issue?

Comment: @FreakyAli Even i have tried with `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` Nuget package along with sqlite-net-pcl . And i did setup on Appdelegate `SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_sqlite3());` But its not working

Comment: Use the one you used in Xamarin sqlite-net-sqlcipher

Comment: I have already tried it. but it is not working